# checkIfPhoneIsSilent() method undefined

Tags: android

I'm following thru the example app in Android Development for Dummies which is a simple application that toggles the ringer mode from silent to normal. For some reason, when I call the checkIfPhoneIsSilent method, it is underlined in red with the error message "the method checkIfPhoneIsSilent is undefined for type Main" Here is the code so far:

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import android.media.AudioManager;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Main extends Activity {

    private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    private boolean mPhoneIsSilent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        checkIfPhoneIsSilent();
        setButtonClickListener();
    }



    private void setButtonClickListener() {
        Button toggleButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mPhoneIsSilent) {
                        //change back to normal
                        mAudioManager
                            .setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                    }

                }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `checkIfPhoneIsSilent` method, is it defined earlier in the book?

Comment: I think you are missing the code for checkIfPhoneIsSilent();

Answer (score 0):

**checkIfPhoneIsSilent** method is as add this method. you are missing it in your code:

```
private void checkIfPhoneIsSilent() {
int ringerMode = mAudioManager.getRingerMode();
if (ringerMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
mPhoneIsSilent = true;
} else {
mPhoneIsSilent = false;
}
}
```

Comment: @ K-ballo, no it's not defined earlier in the book.

Comment: @ imran, I do accept the answer, thank you, I will try it out!